# Detect if Netty connection between two peers break

Tags: java, netty

I am making a High Availablity cluster (Active-Active) in which each node is connected in Line topology (Point to Point connection).

Like this: 
[image: Each node connected to its adjacent peers]

Each node (Java application running on each node) is connected using Netty channel. My question is, how would a Node know whenever there is a connection break with its peer (either right or left)? So that I can restart establishing Netty connection between the nodes.

Can I use `channelInactive(ctx)` method in the handler for this purpose? Or is there any other solution?

Cause of connection break could be anything: Application forcefully stopped on one node, Exception occurred, I/O operation failing etc.

Comment: Netty still using TCP and UDP, so your question is how to know if the TCP/UDP link down. TCP and UDP is an application layer protocol, so will not provide this in time (your HA env), as the TCP timeout is very high. So the only method is to implement your heart-beat message using UDP. TCP also will automatically re-transmission by the OS, so not suitable for heart-beat.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `channelActive`.... That said if you want to detect a remote peer that did go away you will need to implement some sort of "heartbeat" into your protocol to notice it in a timely manner.